# Como voltar ao inicio de uma Array em C#

Tags: c#, array, loop, criptografia, ascii

Tenho que desenvolver um código onde ele faça a criptografia de Cifra de Cesar, os caracteres que devo usar deverá estar nesta sequência; A~Z,(espaço em branco),0~9.
Já desenvolvi boa parte do código, só que me deparei com um problema;

```
for (int i = 0; i < palavra.Length; i++){
//Pego Valor Dec. da palavra
ASCIIP = (int)palavra[i], x = 1, y = 0;
    while (x != 0){
          //Verifico qual índice esta o valor dec.
          if (ASCIIP == tabelaASCII[y]){
             //Somo a chave da cifra
             ASCIIC = tabelaASCII[y + 4];
             //Converto para Char o valor Criptografado
             encrypt += Char.ConvertFromUtf32(ASCIIC);
             x = 0;
             }
          y++;
    }
   return encrypt;
}
```

Meu problema esta na seguinte linha `ASCIIC = tabelaASCII[y + 4];` Como que eu faço para voltar ao inicio da array quando a soma do índice estoura?

Exemplo:

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5}, y = 1, resultado;
resultado = array[y];
/* resultado = 2 */

resultado = array[y+4];
/* resultado = 1 */
```

Comment: A resposta abaixo te ajudou, por favor vote ou de seu comentário sobre a ajudar, para melhorar a questão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso deve resolver seu problema, quando estoura o índice ele volta a zero.

```
for (int i = 0; i < palavra.Length; i++){
//Pego Valor Dec. da palavra
ASCIIP = (int)palavra[i], x = 1, y = 0, num = 4;
    while (x != 0){
          //Verifico qual índice esta o valor dec.
          if (ASCIIP == tabelaASCII[y]){
             num = num == palavra.Length ? 0 : num;
             //Somo a chave da cifra
             ASCIIC = tabelaASCII[num];
             //Converto para Char o valor Criptografado
             encrypt += Char.ConvertFromUtf32(ASCIIC);
             x = 0;
             }
          num++;   
          y++;
    }
   return encrypt;
}
```